# Sending SMS from Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-mobile, sms, activesync

This is the question asked at many places but I could not find any satisfying answer so asking it in stackoverflow. Hope I will get answer soon.

I need to make an Windows Application (VC++/C#/VB.NET) which can send SMS using windows mobile which is connected through ActiveSync or Device center without GSM Modem.

Hope to get positive replies :)

Answer (score 0):

Just so we're clear, you want to use a windows mobile application to send an SMS using the active sync connection to a PC rather than using a WWAN cellular modem?

If the PC is connected to the Internet, I suppose you could use your ActiveSync connection to get Internet access for your mobile device. From there, you could access a web service that allows sending SMS messages. Verizon provides one here: https://text.vzw.com/customer_site/jsp/messaging_lo.jsp

This seems silly, though. Why not just use the device's WLAN to connect to the internet instead of connecting it to a PC? If you must be connected to a PC, why not just use the PC to send the SMS?

-PaulH

Comment: Hi Paul, Some windows mobile do not have WWAN cellular model. I thought there is some way to send direct messages from desktop as Jeyo mobile software is doing for windows mobile. If you have any idea please throw some light on that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that product and their website is scant on technical details. I would assume they're using web services provided by the wireless companies as I suggested. Here's a website that specializes in providing SMS to web applications: http://www.ozekisms.com/